# ISP switched me to Dual-Stack Lite, can't reach my network remotely with IPv6. Used to work with IPv4

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have a Raspberry Pi I use for TeamSpeak, I could simply connect to it.

My ISP gifted me with [Dual-Stack Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism#Dual-Stack_Lite_(DS-Lite)) taking away the IPv4 address I had.

Is there a way for me to simply connect again to my Raspberry Pi with the IPv6 address it now has?

I checked the IP addresses on it:

- net6 address: `fe80::5399:smtn:smtn:smtn/64 Scope:Link`
- inet6 address: `2a02:ab88:568b:d180:smtn:smtn:smtn:smtn/64 Scope:Global`

I tried both addresses, with no luck.

With the change the old forwarding options are gone from the UPC/Vodafone box.

I tried to allow all protocol from all adresses to all adressses but it did not help.

Dual-Stack Lite is such garbage but could not tag it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to simply connect again to my Raspberry Pi with the IPv6 address it now has?

Use the "Scope:Global" address, but make sure both the Raspberry Pi's firewall *and* the router's firewall allow inbound connections — just because there's no NAT, doesn't mean there is no firewall; typically home gateways block inbound connections to your LAN by default and a custom rule is still needed.

Make sure software on the Raspberry Pi is *listening* for connections on that address — if it's TCP, try to `nc -vv ::1 someport` or `ss -ltn | grep someport`. (For example, software configured to listen on 0.0.0.0 will only accept connections at IPv4 addresses, not v6.)

Some ISPs deliberately block inbound connections for non-business customers at ISP network level (can happen for IPv6 as well as IPv4) — ask around whether your ISP has started doing so.

Ignore the "Scope:Local" address, it's mainly for infrastructure usage only.